# How to use gdb command list to print a function's parameter and return value without pausing?

Tags: gdb

I want to see which parameter and return value to a function. I use gdb breakpoint command list (gdb command script) as follow:

```
int foo(int)

(gdb) break foo
(gdb) print $r0
(gdb) finish
(gdb) print $r0
(gdb) continue
(gdb) end
```

But it print only the parameter.

I got the reason from here [GDB Breakpoint command lists](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_35.html)

> Any other commands in the command list, after a command that resumes execution, are ignored.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a second breakpoint at the end of the function if you want to associate commands there.

Comment: I don't have the source code of 'foo()'. How do I find the end of the function foo()'s body?

Comment: When you are stopped at a breakpoint inside foo(), the disassemble command should disassemble the whole function, then set a breakpoint at the last address shown with `break *0xaddress`.  Should be a `retq` or something similar depending on your architecture.  There might be more than one return point shown.  You should set a breakpoint at all of them.